# HTML 5 Drop File only in a div

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces

I am doing JSF primefaces project.We have primefaces file upload component in a div id="dropBox" which accepts drag and drop files.Normally if you drop a file anywhere on the page, browser opens it up.I want to disable this behavior and allow drops only in the div dropBox. following code disables file drag and drops on entire page .

```
$(document).bind({
   dragenter: function (e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
      dt.effectAllowed = dt.dropEffect = 'none';

   },
   dragover: function (e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
        dt.effectAllowed = dt.dropEffect = 'none';

   }
});
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: @dratewka I think he's saying so far that he's only able to disable the whole browser. He wants to disable everything but the div.